# Duda de patrones de diseño en java con constructores que pidan un objeto Conectable

Tags: java, patrones-de-diseño

Estoy programando una conexión con una base de datos y tengo un par de dudas.

Creé una interfaz `Conectable` que pide un método que devuelva un objeto del tipo `Connection`, a su vez cree una clase `ConexionAccess` que la implementa. En ésta, además tuve que crear un singleton para la conexión con la base de datos (no puedo pedirlo con la interfaz `Conectable` porque hasta donde sé no se puede). O sea, `ConexionAccess` me queda con 2 métodos conectar (el singleton) y `getConexion` (el que implementa de `Conectable`), ¿es esto correcto?

Código:

```
public class ConexionAccess implements Conectable
{
     Connection con=null;
     static ConexionAccess conexion=null;

    private ConexionAccess()
    {
        System.out.println("Entre");
        try 
        {
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://planillaDeCaja.accdb");
        } 
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static ConexionAccess Conectar() 
    {
        if(conexion==null)
        {
            conexion=new ConexionAccess();
        }
        else
            System.out.println("no entre");
        return conexion;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        return con;
    }
}
```

La idea de todo esto es hacer Strategys en los DAOImpl (con constructores que pidan un objeto `Conectable`), para poder, en un futuro, usar otro tipo de conexión sin tener que cambiar todo el código. Lo que me hace ruido de todo esto es que para instanciar cualquier implementación de `Conectable` voy a tener que usar un método estático que no es propio de éste.

Ej:

```
Conectable conexion= ConexionAccess.conectar();// devuelve un objeto ConexionAccess
```

¿Esto estaría bien? ¿O me estoy desviando mucho del sendero del clean code? ¿Hay alguna forma de poder pedir métodos estáticos mediante una interfaz?

Comment: Primero que todo tu singletón pudiera no funcionar como tal, agregale la palabra reservada synchronized para evitar que se cree más de un objeto, segundo para que te serviría la interfaz conectable si tu regresas un java.sql.Connection?

Comment: Para el Strategy, si no tendria que implementar directamente la conexion sobre los DAO o no? O lo que decis es que deberia directamente pedir un objeto del tipo connection en los strategys?

Comment: O retornar un Objeto del tipo Conectable ?

Comment: No es buen diseño usar el patrón singleton para las conexiones a las base de datos. Compartir una conexión en una ambiente multi hilos te va a causar errores y posiblemente corrupción de datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La idea es buena, es más es recomendable tener una clase que se encargue de la estrategia de obtener una conexión a la base de datos. Solo hay dos problemas con tu diseño:

1. Usas el patrón singleton. Deberías evitar esto, **especialmente en las conexiones a bases de datos**. Una conexión a base de datos se debería obtener múltiples veces puesto que **siempre debe cerrarse** la conexión. Además, la conexión a base de datos debe ser usada en el ámbito o alcance más corto posible. Al usar singleton, rompes con esta buena práctica puesto que esperarías que la conexión esté abierta siempre durante tu aplicación.
2. Esto luce bien para una aplicación con un solo usuario, como de escritorio. Pero si mueves esto a una aplicación real donde existen miles de usuarios accediendo a ella, como una aplicación web, entonces el diseño se rompe. Esto se debe a que múltiples hilos querrán usar el mismo objeto `Connection`, y los resultados al hacer esto son desastrosos.

Lo mejor sería tener, de momento, una implementación básica de tu interfaz. Este es un ejemplo basado en el código que provees:

```
public class ConexionAccess implements Conectable {
    //atributos definidos como final
    //así solo se les puede asignar valor 1 sola vez
    //este valor no puede cambiar a lo largo de la aplicación

    //el valor de url sería algo como jdbc:ucanaccess://planillaDeCaja.accdb
    private final String url;
    private final String usuario;
    private final String password;

    private ConexionAccess(String url, String usuario, String password) {
        this.url = url;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        Connection con = null;
        try 
        {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                url, usuario, password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //e.getMessage devuelve una cadena
            //no imprime nada, así que esta línea literalmente
            //no hace nada útil para la aplicación
            //e.getMessage();
            //por lo menos deberías imprimir el stacktrace de
            //la excepción
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias muy copada tu respuesta!!! Te hago una pregunta, si descarto el singleton para que dejo el constructor en privado? es para usar el getConnection de conectable no? Tiene sentido esa parte? La de la interfaz digo, o me conviene directamente pedir un objeto connection en los constructores de los DAOImpl?